# Laravel mysql Inner join and also select a specific field from another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, inner-join

I have the following query:

```
Ratings::join('users', 'movieratings.rated_by', '=', 'users.usr_id')
        ->where('rated_on', $movieId)
        ->orderBy('rated_at', 'desc')
        ->select('comment', 'rating', 'rated_as', 'rated_at', 'username')
        ->paginate(20);
```

This will get all the feedback ratings for a specific movie.
But I have another table which contains the total good and bad ratings for a specific movie movie, the only problem is that I cant get it to work to query that table as well at the same time.

If I do another query I would simply write: `Movie::where('movie_id', $movieId)->select('total_good_ratings', 'total_bad_ratings')->get();` this would output eg "**22, 15**" but is it possible to only fetch two columns from a specific row then do a inner join between two tables and paginate the result?

thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use a normal Eloquent relationship instead of a join? Much easier that way.

Comment: @apokryfos Mostly because I am not sure what happens under the hood when I call some of laravels helper functions. I find it easier to write raw sql's as long as they are safe most of the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a leftJoin with the table that contains the good and bad ratings, where the join condition will be the id of the movie.

```
Ratings::join('users', 'movieratings.rated_by', '=', 'users.usr_id')
        ->leftJoin('movie', 'movie.id', '=', 'movieratings.rated_on')
        ->where('rated_on', $movieId)
        ->orderBy('rated_at', 'desc')
        ->select('comment', 'rating', 'rated_as', 'rated_at', 'username', 'total_good_ratings', 'total_bad_ratings')
        ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: This implies that there could be rating without a movie being rated.

Comment: how to put an alias in the select fields?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this:

```
Ratings::leftJoin('users', 'users.usr_id', '=', 'movieratings.rated_by')
        ->leftJoin('movie', 'movie.id', '=', 'movieratings.rated_on')
        ->where('movieratings.rated_on', $movieId)
        ->orderBy('movie.rated_at', 'desc')
        ->select('movieratings.comment', 'movieratings.rating', 'movieratings.rated_as', 'movie.rated_at', 'users.username', 'movieratings.total_good_ratings', 'movieratings.total_bad_ratings')
        ->paginate(20);
```

Hope this help for you !!!

Answer (score 0):

In case this may be of help:

Assuming:

```
class Rating extends Model {
      public users() {
          $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'usr_id');
      }
      public movie() {
          $this->belongsTo(Movie::class, 'rated_on'); //Name looks odd, it should be movie_id if you are following standard conventions
      }
}
```

Then you can lazy/eaher load them:

```
$ratings = Ratings::with([ "movie" => function ($query) {
        $q->select('total_good_ratings', 'total_bad_ratings');
     }])->where('rated_on', $movieId)
       ->orderBy('rated_at', 'desc')
       ->select('comment', 'rating', 'rated_as', 'rated_at', 'username',"rated_on")
       ->paginate(20);
```

You can get the movie info via `$ratings[X]->movie->total_good_ratings` (in a loop that would be `$rating->movie->total_good_ratings`

A bit of critique though:

1. `total_good_ratings` looks like it's a derived attribute so it should not have been stored in the first place. It's appears to be a count of the good ratings.
2. You should use the standard conventions when naming columns and tables e.g. a foreign key is usually called `<foreign table name in singular>_<foreign field name>` example `user_id` or `movie_id` .